# Mvn gae:deploy?

Tags: java, playn

I'm trying to deploy my PlayN game to Google Appengine. With the gae plugin.

http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/

```
mvn -f html/pom.xml gae:deploy
```

But it doesn't work! Get this ..

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Memory HTML 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-gae-plugin:0.9.2:deploy (default-cli) @ memory-html >>>
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/memory-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/memory-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[WARNING] The POM for memory:memory-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/memory-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/memory-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.508s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 12 21:16:27 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/82M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project memory-html: Could not resolve dependencies for project memory:memory-html:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact memory:memory-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in fo
rplay-legacy (http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

What does it mean? What could be wrong?

--

Edit:

Here's my [/html/pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/UAdP4tLy)

Comment: It looks like Maven can't find the `memory-core` artifact. I'm assuming this is one of yours? Have you built this artifact yet, so Maven can find it in your local repository?

Comment: Pasting your pom.xml could help to find the problem

Comment: I have added a link to my pom.xml, if it helps.

Comment: I have a memory-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in memory/core/target, and in maven repository I have memory/memory-core/1.0-SNAPSHOT/memory-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.lastUpdated, but don't know what that means.

Comment: Running "mvn integration-test -Phtml" makes a working HTML build and fires up working local build.